# How do I fix the error "The type initializer for '?' threw an exception." when sending e-mails through C# with EASendMail?

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp

I have been working on this project to send an e-mail to a user and I have had an error come up all the time. (I'm using the EASendMail NuGet package) It is "The type initializer for '?' threw an exception." (this is in the console for the error system that the package has) I dont really know what that means, my code is this:

```
using EASendMail;

namespace Email
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                SmtpMail oMail = new SmtpMail("TryIt");

                // Set sender email address, please change it to yours
                oMail.From = "Splat2ooner@gmail.com";
                // Set recipient email address, please change it to yours
                oMail.To = "Splat2ooner@gmail.com";

                // Set email subject
                oMail.Subject = "test email from c# project";
                // Set email body
                oMail.TextBody = "this is a test email sent from c# project, do not reply";

                // SMTP server address
                SmtpServer oServer = new SmtpServer("smtp.gmail.com");

                // User and password for ESMTP authentication
                oServer.User = "Splat2ooner@gmail.com";
                oServer.Password = "password (not my passoword)";

                // Most mordern SMTP servers require SSL/TLS connection now.
                // ConnectTryTLS means if server supports SSL/TLS, SSL/TLS will be used automatically.
                oServer.ConnectType = SmtpConnectType.ConnectTryTLS;

                // If your SMTP server uses 587 port
                //oServer.Port = 587;

                // If your SMTP server requires SSL/TLS connection on 25/587/465 port
                //oServer.Port = 25; // 25 or 587 or 465
                oServer.ConnectType = SmtpConnectType.ConnectSSLAuto;

                Console.WriteLine("start to send email ...");

                SmtpClient oSmtp = new SmtpClient();
                oSmtp.SendMail(oServer, oMail);

                Console.WriteLine("email was sent successfully!");
            }
            catch (Exception ep)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("failed to send email with the following error:");
                Console.WriteLine(ep.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: FYI When I said password (Not my password) in the real code it is my password.

Comment: As I dont have the package (and it looks enough like the normal c# smtp client that Id have stuck with that) what does SmtpMail("TryIt"); .. what is that tryit parameter supposed to be for?

Comment: It's an object from the class included in the NuGet package and TryIt is an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like newer version of "**EASendMail**" (as of now the latest version is **7.5.0.3**) package has this issue.

I don't have much time to do research on it, just installed older version (**7.3.1.2**) and it resolved this.

hope it helps.